# In Fieldrunners (iPhone) what is a good strategy for the Marathon Challenge in Grasslands?

Tags: fieldrunners

As the question says, I can't get above LVL 33 and I'm aligning 7 Teslas in the middle of the field in a line but it doesn't seem to work right.